# Salesforce REST API getting an error 401

Tags: salesforce

I am using REST API get information from Salesforce to my PHP page. After a long time don't use on PHP page I take a error message "failed with status 401, response [{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}], curl_error , curl_errno 0". Please help me how to recall Authentication on php to avoid session timeout? I want my Page is always connection to Salesforce. please tell me other suggestions to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

The session ID or OAuth token used has expired or is invalid. The response body contains the message and errorCode. - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/errorcodes.htm

Comment: Thanks for your replying, can take the status back, but I want to ask that we can recall Salesforce or do any ways we do not take the error?

Comment: Sorry, I'm reading your words and can't combine them into sentence. What I was trying to said in my answer is that usually I got this error when I had wrong password/token or user didn't have rights to use API.

Answer (score 0):

Just catch that 401 error and reauthenticate.

Or use the refreshToken when using Oauth. As documented here: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com